# Ethereum blockchain guide

Tags: ethereumjs

I am building a digital property papers project on blockchain. I am new to this tech. I wanna know some resources for blockchain development. Also I wanna know how much a single transaction cost is on Ethereum.

Comment: Hi UmairNadeem! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Can you be a bit more specific about what are you looking for? Research papers, existing projects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [repository](https://github.com/frankiefab100/Blockchain-Development-Resources) with lots of resources

Comment: Hi Oli! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Link only answer are discouraged. It is better to include the more important bits in the answer and only use the link to expand the details.

Answer (score 0):

Umair Nadeem.  There is a great deal of development information on the Ethereum.org site:  https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/

The founding "white paper" by Vitalik Buterin can be viewed at https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/

Welcome to the future; fab_rat